# Alter Statement Working in MySQl but not in MAriaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Why does not this statment work in Distrib 10.1.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64), but works in MySQL?

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED 
WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyPassword';
```

Error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near  USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED 
>   WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyPassword';

Thanks.

Comment: The only mention of "mysql_native_password" in the maria db docs [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-user/) suggests it is only relevant when plugins are involved; perhaps it is one of the points where the two must differ from each other.

Comment: It would be so much easier to help you if you provided the exact error message instead of the meaningless "not working"...

Comment: does MariaDb root account to authenticate with a password by default, I see unux_socket authentication as default.

Comment: there I added the error.

Comment: You missed the most important part of the error message: the part of the sql statement where the syntax error occured.

Comment: I added complete error it says near the whole statement minus ALTER keyword.

Answer (score 5):

The `ALTER USER` statement was introduced in *MariaDB 10.2.0* (You are in *10.1.29*) and that's the issue here. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/error-1604/

Comment: I'm on version `10.6.12` yet I stil get the same error